# Correct way to sort a slice of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Pandas, and constantly getting the infamous SettingWithCopyWarning. If I have code like the following I get the warning:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

t1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randn(8), 'B': np.random.randint(0,4,8)})

table = t1[t1['B'] < 3]

print(table)

table.sort(['B'], inplace=True)

print(table)
```

1. In this case, is it just warning me that the original data frame (i.e., 't1') will not be sorted when I run the sort?
2. Is there a more accepted way to perform this sort of operation (getting a slice of a data frame, and then applying functions on that slice)?

Comment: Well the warning is telling that your op will not affect the orig df, which may be what you intended, if you take a copy of a slice then the warning goes away and it becomes explicit that you are intending to operate on a copy: `table = t1[t1['B'] < 3].copy()`

Answer (score 2):

Why not make a copy of the slice? Then you will not have the warning.

```
a = table.copy()
```

You can read more in the answers to this post [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-this-pandas-warning).

Answer (score 1):

You can also avoid to use `inplace`, in this case the copy will be made behind the scene for you.

```
t1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randn(8), 'B': np.random.randint(0,4,8)})
table = t1[t1['B'] < 3]
table = table.sort(['B'])
print(table)
```